# Why simple polygons in plane have this property?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

If we are given a [simple polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) $P$ in the plane by the points $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$. How can we prove that there are $3$ consecutive points $A_i, A_{i+1}, A_{i+2}$ (if $i = n$, for $A_{i + 1}$ and $A_{i+2}$ I mean $A_1$ and $A_2$ of course) such that there isn't another point $A_j$ in the triangle $A_i A_{i+1}A_{i+2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a simple polygon with at least one exception:
[image: Simple Polygon with Exception]

It is easy to prove that this is impossible with 4 or less vertices, so remove any offending vertex and replace with a line connecting the other two. This reduces to one of the cases mentioned before, and was part of the original polygon.

Comment: What do you mean by "exception"?

Comment: Take a simple polygon for which the property in the question holds at all times. So I have called a triangle which breaks this rule an exception, although it could refer to vertices inside such a triangle.

Comment: I'm not sure this works. The argument is basically that if you have a polygon $A_1...A_{n+1}$, and $A_{n+1}$ is inside the triangle $A_iA_{i+1}A_{i+2}$, then you remove $A_{n+1}$ to get the polygon $A_1...A_n$. Then if you can find a triangle in that that works, that triangle works for $A_1...A_{n+1}$ as well. But that's not true - what if the triangle you found was $A_iA_{i+1}A_{i+2}$ ?